# How to store a line coordinates in a list?

Tags: c#, list, graphics, line

I want to store the coordinates of lines in a list in c#. I have created a list:

```
List<int> lijst = new List<int>();
```

and I want to store the following lines in that list:

```
canvas.DrawLine(pen, xStart, yStart, xStart, yStart - Height);
canvas.DrawLine(pen, xStart, yStart, xStart + Width, yStart);
canvas.DrawLine(pen, xStart, yStart - Height, xStart + Width, yStart - Height);
canvas.DrawLine(pen, xStart + Width, yStart, xStart + Width, yStart - Height);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: That's a list of just integers. A line isn't an integer. Have you considered creating a `Line` class (if there isn't already a suitable one) and creating a `List<Line>` instead?

Comment: Maybe make a list of line objects instead of integers.

Comment: `Graphics.DrawLine()` does not return a value. Assuming you use this.

Comment: Use List<List<int>>

Comment: You either create a class or structure to represent the line and store it, or use a existing structure to store each coordinate (ValueTuple, Tuple, List<double>, double[]) and store that structure.

Comment: What type is `canvas`, I would assume a `Graphics` object?

Comment: Canvas is indeed a graphics object

Comment: System does not accept that

Answer (score 3):

**Using a list of DrawLineItem**

```
var lijst = new List<DrawLineItem>();
```

**The DrawLineItem class**

```
public class DrawLineItem
{
  public Pen Pen { get; set; }
  public int StartX { get; set; }
  public int StartY { get; set; }
  public int EndX { get; set; }
  public int EndY { get; set; }
  public DrawLineItem(Pen pen, int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
  {
    Pen = pen;
    StartX = startX;
    StartY = startY;
    EndX = endX;
    EndY = endY;
  }
}
```

You can remove setters if modification is not allowed.

You can replace `int` by `single` if needed.

You can remove `Pen` if not needed.

You can use the same pattern with `Point` or `PointF` if you need to use some overloaded `DrawLine` method.

**Usage**

```
lijst.Add(new DrawLineItem(pen, xStart, yStart, xStart, yStart - Height));
lijst.Add(new DrawLineItem(pen, xStart, yStart, xStart + Width, yStart));
lijst.Add(new DrawLineItem(pen, xStart, yStart - Height, xStart + Width, yStart - Height));
lijst.Add(new DrawLineItem(pen, xStart + Width, yStart, xStart + Width, yStart - Height));
```

**Advice**

You should rename `lijst` that is an unclean name in `listDrawLines` for example.

So you can for example do such thing:

```
foreach ( var item in listDrawLines )
  canvas.DrawLine(item.Pen, item.StartX, item.StartY, item.EndX, item.EndY);
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try!

Comment: I tried, but the foreach does not work because listdrawlines does not exist in the current context according to the compiler

Comment: The problem is that the foreach loop of Olivier is in a different class than where I have my foreach loop. Because it is a local variable, I can't use it. Any idea how to solve this? @CharlesP

Comment: @Friso I don't understand. `listDrawLines` comes from a suggested renaming of `lijst` by pressing F2 key on it...

Comment: Should the usage part of your answer be in the class "drawlineitem"? Right now, I have the usage part in a different class.

Answer (score 0):

use a

```
var lijst = new List<(Pen, Point, Point)>();
```

where Point is System.Drawing.Point

Comment: OP is using the overload of `DrawLine(Pen, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)`... it has a few different signatures. TBH, the answer is wrong.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ why is it wrong? i'm sure he'll figure it out.
A line needs a pen and two points, so its the most readable solution, apart from using an extra class.

Comment: `why is it wrong?` because the OP clearly isn't using just a `pen` and two `points`...

Comment: Technically it's not clear if he's using `Point` or `PointF` types, but if the `StartX` arguments are `int`, this would technically work, but the answer should then describe how you would populate such a list from the give sample code, since the `Point` objects need to be created.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ: I still don't get it. I will paste some additional code to see if you can help. I have to implement a bridge pattern. There is an abstract class shape, shape can either be a rectangle or a triangle. The lines of the rectangle or triangle have to be stored. Via the implementation the rectangle or triangle is drawn on the screen

Comment: ok, what is your question? Olivier posted a detailed solution how to store and repaint the values. Do you wanna store them in a database, or in a file? then you might need serialization.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class Shape
{
    protected string description;
    protected Color edgeColor;
    protected Pen pen;
    public Weergave Weergave;

    //public line lijnen;
    //public List<int> lijst;

    public virtual void Draw(ShapeDisplay sd, Graphics canvas)
    {
        // we define a uniform pen size for all shapes
        //pen = new Pen(this.edgeColor, 3);
        Weergave.Draw1(sd, canvas);
    }
}

public abstract class Weergave
{
    protected Color randkleur;
    protected Pen pen;

    public virtual void Draw1(ShapeDisplay sd, Graphics canvas)
    {
        pen = new Pen(this.randkleur, 3);
    }
}
public class Graphical : Weergave
{
    public override void Draw1(ShapeDisplay sd, Graphics canvas)
    {
        foreach (var item in) 
    }
}
```

In the operation 'weergave.draw1(sd,canvas) another class is called upon. The class 'weergave'. In this class the actual lines from rectangle or shape should be drawn